# Android-How to use a fragment to display a webview

Tags: android, webview, null, fragment

Im updating some of my older projects and using fragments to update the look of things. I tried to use a fragment to launch a webview but when I try to run it I get the following error in my logcat.

```
 E/Web Console(22464): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at    
 http://m.yahoo.com/?.tsrc=yahoo&mobile_view_default=true:1
```

The way I used to use a webview was to just create a class that was its own activity that took place in a webview but I would like to have a small view within a fragment and then when I wanted to use the class I would launch it via intent and pass anything I needed to the webview like a url and other parameters in extras within the intent. I tried just setting up a webview within a fragment but I havent gotten it to work yet. This is the code Im using for the moment.

```
    public class WebViewer extends Fragment {
WebView Wv;
String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
Activity act;
public WebViewer(){}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.act = activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container);

      Wv = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
      Wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      Wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
      Wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
      Wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      Wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
      Wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      Wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                {
                    act.setTitle("Loading...");
                    act.setProgress(progress * 100);             
                    if(progress == 100)
                        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                }
            });
      Wv.loadUrl(url);

    return mView;

}
}
```

And then this is the layout for the activity that uses this fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
 >

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/webFragment"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="my.proj.WebViewer"></fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

So how can I get a webview to open inside a fragment I can use in a view.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html       I just found that a minute ago.....ill post back here with how I get it to work when I finally do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161192/webviewfragment-webview-is-null-after-doing-a-fragmenttransaction     I think I may go with what I found at the link here. I couldnt get the webviewfragment to work and there wasnt to much documentation on it on the doc site other than the list of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about just extending [WebViewFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html)?

Comment: Note that this answer is from 2013, and the documentation says, "This class was deprecated in API level 28."