# Converting webview into a Bitmap

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I'm trying to load a webview with some html code and then capture it and turn into a Bitmap. However, all I can see in the ImageView I set to test it, is a blank square.

```
webViewToPrint.loadDataWithBaseURL("", dataStringHtml , "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
webViewToPrint.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              super.onPageFinished(view, url);

              Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( view.getHeight(), view.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);
              Canvas canvas = new Canvas( b );
              view.draw(canvas);
              imageView.setImageBitmap(b);       
        }});
```

Comment: i this may  help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409630/how-to-capture-the-webview-to-bitmap-in-android-5-0

Answer (score 1):

```
 webViewToPrint.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                    Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
                    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                    picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );
                    picture.draw( c );
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);    }}
```

Comment: the imageView is empty.. now it doesn't even show a white rectangle like it used to

Comment: what version u are testing? add this one also hope to help if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webview.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw ();
}  make sure you call this method before calling setContentView() in your onCreate()

Comment: My device is API 19, so I can't use enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the help. The solution tough was to add another thread (postDelayed) inside onPageFinished with some delay (500 worked fine in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
webViewToPrint.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

**In onPageFinished()**

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```